# What causes gravity?

Tags: gravity

What causes gravity? Why is there attraction between masses? Is it due to time or space distortion?

Comment: I suggest that you start with the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation) and then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: I agree with @gigacyan.    As it stands, it's a very confused question, which is clear to   from the last sentence "Is it due to time or space distortion?".  This site isn't meant to *teach* you something, but we can onl(y answer your questions . . .               )

Comment: I think he asked what is the mechanism behind gravity...

Comment: https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=175

Answer (score 1):

I would say, it is rather vague to ask this "why" questions in physics when you are talking about fundamental things. We may say that gravity is a consequence of a deep symmetry of nature, called general covariance, which says that every reference frame should be equally suitable for the description of the laws of physics and it follows that the geometry of the spacetime is affected by the distribution of energy which is described by the Einstein's equations in simplest way. Particles follow straightest line called geodesic in this curved geometry. However this is actually "how" gravity works. What causes gravity may still be a vague question since gravity, as per current wisdom, is a fundamental interaction in nature. You just can not "explain" it from other simpler facts. Some recent attempts try to project it as less fundamental (like gravity is an entropic force). But that is very much controversial.

Comment: Um, no, gravity is not a consequence of general covariance. Even if you have your space-time described by a manifold (even pseudo-Riemannian) that still doesn't tell you anything about interaction of the space-time and matter. To arrive at Einstein's equations you need lots of additional assumptions. There exist other theories of gravitation (even consistent with Einstein's in certain limit). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity

Comment: Dear @Marek, your complaint in this case seems to be missing logic. You don't need Einstein's equations to get gravity. SB1 only claims that gravity is a consequence of general covariance and it is true. General covariance requires a gauge field to exist, and this gauge field inevitably contributes terms to the action such as the Einstein-Hilbert action - which inevitably cause gravity between matter (whose terms in the action existed before we considered general covariance). You don't disprove this statement by sb1 by inserting new unnecessary intermediate links to the implication.

Comment: Moreover, Marek, the page you linked to is very bizarre. All the entries are theories claiming to respect general covariance, and except for LQG, they actually do. So even if we could assume that these alternatives were right, it wouldn't disprove the implication "general covariance implies gravity". Moreover, none of them except for the first ones - Brans-Dicke - may be understood as "alternatives to GR". They're extensions of GR that also solve other things, but the gravitational portion of them is exactly GR. E.g. Kaluza-Klein theory is "more GR" than GR plus Maxwell's system.

Comment: @Luboš: you've completely missed the point. Note that sb1 mentions Einstein's equations in his answer as well ;) Unless I am misreading, he's saying that Einstein's equations are a consequence of general covariance which is simply not true and it's this thing that I reacted to.

Comment: @MareK: I thought by writing "described by Einstein's equations in *simplest way*" I will get away with this criticism. I guess my English is not good enough. I am very much aware that general covariance does not lead by itself to Einstein's equations. There are many other alternatives. But Einstein's equations are simplest possible. That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: @sb1: okay then; so it was just me misreading you, sorry.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, Gravitons could also be attributable to why gravity exists. An explanation of gravitons would be too extensive for this answer box. You can read more on the [Gravitons wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) or google for more reference on the topic.

Comment: Gravity is something mankind has some experience of, eg self-harvesting apples. Gravitons may be likely, but not prooven. So, anwering the (layman's) "why" by gravitons does not help. Maybe the  questioner is impressed by another buzzword, but he does not know more than before.

Comment: Completely agree. It was just another explanation. Also forgot to mention they were theoretical.

Answer (score -1):

[Wikipedia  (on Aether Theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories) cites Isaac Newton:

"Doth not this aethereal medium in passing out of water, glass, crystal, and other compact and dense bodies in empty spaces, grow denser and denser by degrees, and by that means refract the rays of light not in a point, but by bending them gradually in curve lines?  ... Is not this medium much rarer within the dense bodies of the Sun, stars, planets and comets, than in the empty celestial space between them? And in passing from them to great distances, doth it not grow denser and denser perpetually, and thereby

***cause the gravity***

of those great bodies towards one another, and of their parts towards the bodies; every body endeavouring to go from the denser parts of the medium towards the rarer?""

Newton speaks of curve-lines,  not considers forces at the prism, but gravitational force. Since Newton, there haven't been seen any  better explanatory theories, as  my textbook says that among the four basic forces (eletro-magnetic, weak, strong and gravitional force)  gravitation, counterintuitively, still is the one least understood.

Comment: It doth not. Modern conceptions of spacetime geometries bear superficial aesthetic similarity to an invisible, intangible substance but no actual substance is involved.

Comment: I can't understand why this answer is downvoted. If one look at terminal speed under gravity, it depends upon density, I say density of both object and medium. This is evident in buyoancy in denser fluid.