# What's the reason behind Earth's gravity?

Tags: gravity, earth

How can Earth attract any object irrespective of what it is made?

Comment: Questions (1) & (4) have appeared here before (e.g., [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4788/what-causes-gravity)), (2) appears to be answered [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29273/how-does-earths-interior-dynamo-work).

Comment: Your question is basically asking us to explain general relativity, or at least asking us to explain the particular solution to GR called the Schwarzschild metric. This is far too broad a question to be usefully answered here.

Comment: @JohnRennie I edited my question, could you please unhold my question?

Comment: I can't unhold your question: the best I could do is vote to reopen. However in your place I'd abandon the question and ask a new one. However consider that all matter is made of the same elementary particles, so it's not suprising all matter is affected by gravity in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the mass of the Earth. Its mass creates a gravitational field around it so anything that is inside the gravitational field of the Earth, would feel the gravitational force the Earth is exerting on the object. In the same way because of Newton's third law, the Earth would feel a gravitational force towards the object of the same magnitude it exerts over it.

The core of the Earth contains convecting currents due to highly conductive fluids, this creates electric currents which are the cause of the Earth`s magnetic field.The force of gravity acts between two objects of any mass, and since the mass of the Earth is bigger compared to a simple object as a car, then the Earth attracts any object.

The reason is that any body creates a gravitational field around it, so the massive the object, the stronger the gravitational force it exerts. Also since the gravitational force is inversely proportional to the square of the distance, then the closer it is the strongest is the gravitation force. E=MC2