# What is the cause of gravitional force of attraction?

Tags: gravity

Ok,this is a silly question. But for quite long I have been thinking about this. **What is gravitation all about**?? My book directly writes since force of gravitation is directly proportional to the masses and inversly proportional to the square of the distance ie. $$F = G\frac{M_1 . M_2}{r^2}$$ . So is this gravitation all about? What is the cause of it? The book then says

> We are not in the scope in classical approach so as to discuss the cause of this. However,as a matter of fact that if there are more than one mass,then there is gravitation as it is their fundamental property.( Cause of gravitation can be attributed to exchange of **non-classical particles** between the masses) .

Then it ended the talkings. What are those non-classical particles? Why and how are they exchanged? So far I have studied physics , I never found such weird phenomenon like this. I want to know what is the cause of gravitation and what is the cause of exchange of those so-called **non-classical** particles? And how do they do it?

Comment: Those particles are supposed to be gravitons.

Comment: There is no gravitational force (and there wasn't one in Newton's time, either). Gravity is an acceleration of a test mass by another mass. The best description we have makes gravity a distortion of the spacetime metric. Gravitons and more generally all approaches to microscopic explanations for gravity are pure speculation at the moment.

Comment: Apparently gravitons are the particles that allow for the existence of gravity but they have never been experimentally confirmed to exist last I checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4788/2451

Comment: Interestingly, you mention "square of the distance" along with "exchange of particles." If the latter were interaction, math. set theory would define the number of exchanges by square only if on both sides there were the same amount of particles, if the two bodies differ in number of interactive particels that would be the product, not the square. Interestingly, the formula has both. By intuition, masses involved differ, while, as it occurs both "sides" in spite of their being different in mass  seem to be  equal  in "distance" (square of). It occurs: think of  "center courts", concentrating.

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, the only thing that can explain a physical theory is a better theory. Newton's force law used to be the entire theory of gravitation up until the early 1900's. Newton himself had no explanation for what "caused" the force.

Einstein gave us General Relativity, which describes how gravity is the geometry of space and time. In GR, energy and momentum curve spacetime, and objects simply follow the straightest possible path through the curved spacetime! So Newton's law is "explained" by GR.

With the success of Quantum Field Theory at describing the other three fundamental forces (electromagnetism, weak nuclear, and strong nuclear), physicists have been trying very hard to create a quantum description of gravity, though none have been completely successful so far. In QFT each force is described by a field. For example, the electromagnetic field. When the field is "excited," or in other words when the field goes to a higher energy state, the excitations of this field are called photons. When you run through the math of QFT, you find that two like charges placed in the photon field will repel each other with a force that varies as $1/r^2$! This is because the two charges raise the energy state of the field. Similarly, what we *do* know is that if you put two objects in a simplified massless spin-2 field, you get an attractive force between the objects that varies as $1/r^2$! The force comes from each object coupling to the field and lowering its energy. Excitations of this field are called "gravitons." There is as of yet no direct evidence that gravitons exist, and it's highly unlikely that there will be any any time soon given how weakly they are predicted to interact.

Comment: +1, a slightly more technical article on the possibilities of graviton detection [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0601043v3.pdf). It is basically impossible to directly detect a graviton and identify the signal.

Comment: *"So Newton's law is "explained" by GR."* The equations of general relativity have been chosen from many possible relativistic equations so that they lead to the same result as Newton's theory in certain mathematical limit. For example, the Einstein gravitational constant $\kappa$ is chosen so that the the above limit leads to Newton's constant $G$.

Comment: There is no more explanation for the value of $\kappa$ in Einstein's theory than for $G$ in Newton's theory, so it makes little sense to say Newton's gravitation has been explained by general relativity. It is more accurate to say that general relativity is one possible extension of Newtonian theory of gravitation to include the ideas of relativity.

Comment: @JánLalinský - GR is anything but an extension of Newton's theory. It is a complete replacement. Look at the math, the descriptions of space and time. It is true that any theory of gravitation must yield results comparable to Newtonian mechanics in the Newtonian limit. Failure to do so would immediately falsify that new theory. This does not however mean that that theory is "an extension of Newtonian theory of gravitation."

Comment: In a similar vein, that quantum mechanics must also yield results comparable to Newtonian mechanics in the macroscopic limit does not mean that QM is an extension of Newtonian mechanics. Finally, that Newtonian mechanics needed to yield results comparable to Aristotelian physics in the Aristotelian limit does not mean that Newtonian mechanics is an extension of Aristotelian physics. Just as Newtonian mechanics was a complete replacement of Aristotelian physics, both QM and GR are complete replacements of Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @David, I cannot agree with your view. This is not a good place to resolve the disagreement, so let's agree to disagree.

Comment: This is nice, but I'd like to pick a nit. Where you say *"when the field goes to a higher energy state, the excitations of this field are called photons."* the naming of the excitation as a photon is specific to one particular field. Maybe better if you clarify that photons are excitations of the electromagnetic filed in particular.

Answer (score -3):

Currently, there is no generally accepted explanation of why objects attract each other. There are hypotheses such as Le Sage's, but none remained popular. The most basic (simplest) theory of gravitation is still Newton's law of universal gravitation.

Comment: You are forgetting general relativity.

Comment: Why do you think that? Newton's theory is more basic (simpler) than general relativity - the latter was built as an extension of the former.