# what is causing gravitational pull in between massive bodies?

Tags: gravity

what is causing gravitational pull in between massive bodies?

> according to books, what i learnt is graviton particle & some books are saying quantum field is the cause, so which is causing gravitational pull?

Comment: They may well be two aspect of the same - gravitons being elementary excitations of gravitation field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4788/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone really knows. If someone says that the "quantum field" is the cause, it begs the question, what is the cause of the "quantum field". All we know, evidenced by experiment, is that masses attract.

The same argument could be made of what causes an object to fall to the ground, and we might be happy with the answer: gravity.

Comment: *"If someone says that the 'quantum field' is the cause, it begs the question, what is the cause of the 'quantum field'"*. And it also begs the question, how can a particle pull a body (or another particle)? It's easy to propose a pushing mechanism - by bombardment of particles. But pulling ...?